# sending html page inside email nodemailer node.js

Tags: html, node.js, backend, nodemailer

I want to send a payment form inside an email using node.js nodemailer.

My emails are successfully sent, but when I add an HTML file that I created the email has errors.

```
const fs = require("fs");
const { promisify } = require("util");
const readFile = promisify(fs.readFile);

let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
  service: "gmail",
  auth: {
    user: "mymail",
    pass: "mypass",
  },
});

let mailOptions = {
          from: "testeamil@gmail.com",
          to: invoice.customeremail,
          subject: "Payment forServices",
          text: "Please pay to Recieve the order ",
          html: readFile("C://Users//admin//task//payment.html", "utf8"),
        };

        transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function (err, data) {
          if (err) {
            console.log("error", err);
          } else {
            console.log("email sent!");
          }
        });
```

I want the HTML file to be displayed in my email. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: You have turned `fs.readFile` into a promise, therefore the value of `html` in `mailOptions` is a pending promise which is not a valid string. Just use the `fs.readFileSync` method instead or call `await readFile` which will give an error because it's not in an `async` function.

Comment: `error TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "chunk" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer. Received an instance of Promise
    at validChunk (_stream_writable.js:281:10)
    at PassThrough.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:316:21)
    at PassThrough.Writable.end (_stream_writable.js:585:10)
    at Immediate._onImmediate (C:\Users\admin\B.O.T task\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\mime-node\index.js:959:46)
    at processImmediate (internal/timers.js:456:21) {
  code: 'ESTREAM',
  command: 'API'
}`

Comment: i get this error @Milo

Comment: @jayzee Wrap your `mailoptions` and `sendMail()` into `fs.readFile()` that will solve your issue.

Comment: i didn't quite understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to me the right way to send `html` markup using node mailer can be achieved by wrapping your `mailOptions` and `transporter.sendMail()` function into the `fs.readFile()` like this:

First we will correctly read the `html` file using fs and when we will have the file in the callback function in the `html` variable we can send it with the email.

```
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
var fs = require('fs');

var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
 service: 'gmail',
 auth: {
   user: 'youremail@gmail.com',
   pass: 'yourpassword'
 }
});

fs.readFile('Path here', {encoding: 'utf-8'}, function (err, html) {
 if (err) {
   console.log(err);
 } else {
   let mailOptions = {
     from: 'youremail@gmail.com',
     to: 'myfriend@gmail.com',
     subject: 'Sending Html in node mailer',
     html: html
   };

   transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info) {
    if (error) {
     console.log(error);
    } else {
     console.log('Email has been sent: ' + info.response);
    }
  });
 }
});
```

Comment: i will try that

Comment: @jayzee try it and let me know in the comments.

Comment: i cant make it work... idk why 
can u help me on skype or its not possible?

Comment: are you getting any error ? I have added the complete file in code. Now Just change the credentials and try!

Comment: and replace `html` with the path?

Comment: Can you see the `fs.readFile('path here')` replace path here with your html file path. that's it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221785/discussion-between-jayzee-and-mohammad-basit).

Answer (score 0):

I made some modifications to **Mohammad Basit's** answer to allow me to pass a modified link into the email.

On one line of my html file, I created a link that looks like this:

`<a href="mySite.herokuapp.com/resetPassword/#replaceWithLink#">Reset Password</a>`

Then I used JavaScript's [String replace()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp) method to replace the `#replaceWithLink#` text with whatever I want after the file is loaded with `fs.readFile`.

Here's a snippet from my app.js node file:

```
//Sends password reset email
const sendPassResetEmail = function(emailAddress){
  //email host information
  const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: 'smtp.gmail.com',
    port: 465,
    secure: true,
    auth:{
      user: process.env.gmailUsr,
      pass: process.env.gmailPass
    }
  });

  fs.readFile('./emails/passwordReset.html', {encoding: 'utf-8'}, (err, data)=>{
    let htmlFile = data;
    htmlFile = htmlFile.replace("#replaceWithLink#", "myOtherLinkTest")

    if(err){
      console.warn("Error getting password reset template: " + err);
    }else{
      transporter.sendMail({
        from:'"TedCounter :)"<EMAIL-ADDRESS-HERE>',
        to: emailAddress,
        subject:"Ted Counter",
        html: htmlFile
      });
    }
  });
}
```

The result is `#replaceWithLink#` is replaced with `myOtherLinkTest` in the email.